# What is the difference between "expose" and "publish" in Docker?

Tags: docker, port, publish, docker-run

I'm experimenting with Dockerfiles, and I think I understand most of the logic. However, I don't see the difference between "exposing" and "publishing" a port in this context.

All the tutorials I have seen first include the `EXPOSE` command in the Dockerfile:

```
...
EXPOSE 8080
...
```

They then build an image from this Dockerfile:

```
$ docker build -t an_image - < Dockerfile
```

And then *publish* the same port as above when running the image:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080 an_image
```

or publish all ports using

```
$ docker run -d -P an_image
```

What is the point of exposing a port in the Dockerfile, if it will be published anyway? Would there ever be a need to expose a port first, and *not* publish it later? Effectively, I would like to specify all the ports that I will use in the Dockerfile when creating the image, and then not bother with them again, running them simply with:

```
$ docker run -d an_image
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 953, accepted):

Basically, you have three (four) options:

1. Neither specify `EXPOSE` nor `-p`
2. Only specify `EXPOSE`
3. Specify `EXPOSE` and `-p`
4. Only specify `-p` which implicitly does `EXPOSE`

1. If you specify neither `EXPOSE` nor `-p`, the service in the container will only be accessible from *inside* the container itself.
2. If you `EXPOSE` a port, the service in the container is not accessible from outside Docker, but from inside other Docker containers. So this is good for inter-container communication.
3. If you `EXPOSE` and `-p` a port, the service in the container is accessible from anywhere, even outside Docker.
4. If you do `-p`, but do not `EXPOSE`, Docker does an implicit `EXPOSE`. This is because if a port is open to the public, it is automatically also open to other Docker containers. Hence `-p` includes `EXPOSE`. This is effectively same as 3).

The reason why both are separated is IMHO because:

- choosing a host port depends on the host and hence does not belong to the Dockerfile (otherwise it would be depending on the host),
- and often it's enough if a service in a container is accessible from other containers.

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) explicitly states:

> The `EXPOSE` instruction exposes ports for use within links.

It also points you to how to [link containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) (legacy feature), which basically is the inter-container communication I talked about.

Comment: I think that you are not correct with EXPOSE. From other containers, you can access all container ports without exposing them. I tried that. The catch here is that container IP address is unpredictable. I believe that link is used to specify which container you want to connect (so you link to specific container IP), not to enable connection.

Comment: yes, @jiri is right. I think the meaning of EXPOSE instruction is set the environment variable automatically by docker when the container being linked by others which can access the container by variable.

Comment: "If you do not specify any of those", would be useful if you clarified that with "those" you mean `EXPOSE` and `-p` and not the the three bullet points precedented. Got me confused there a bit.

Comment: As my test, If you do not specify any of those, the service in the container WILL BE accessible from docker host and other container by the container's IP address, but not accessible from outeside the docker host. I am using Docker Toolbox 1.12.0-rc3  in Mac OS X

Comment: To be fully complete, this answer should also address a fourth possible case: you didn't specify `EXPOSE`, but you *did* specify `-p`.  It's my understanding that if you always use `-p` and run individual containers then `EXPOSE` is fine to omit, but it becomes useful/necessary when using `-P` or `--link`.  (And since you don't know how other people will use your image, `EXPOSE` should be specified in any public images.)

Comment: so you can't say in a dockerfile : " hey I want the host port to be 80 " ? It would make sens for a server

Comment: Exactly: You can't. The reason for this is that you don't know in advance what else will be run on the host, so it does not make any sense to hard-code this.

Comment: The docs no longer state "The EXPOSE instruction exposes ports for use within links".

Comment: Downvote because this is substantially incorrect.  Expose is basically documentation, and not using it does not restrict access.  This is a dangeros misunderstanding if anyone relies on it to limit access.

Comment: it seems like your answer is outdated. it might be helpful to edit the answer to point out this fact and link to @tgogos answer below (at the time of writing this comment), link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/what-is-the-difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker/47594352#47594352

Comment: would you possibly mention an example of both -p and EXPOSE command ? 
Let's say we have: 
docker run -d --name maria -e 'root' -p 3306:3306  mysql/mysql-server

Comment: generally, what is the best practice to pass a switch for exposing a service to anywhere outside Docker ?

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse but I am wondering why this is still the accepted answer when, like others have stated, this isn't correct. You can absolutely map a host port to a running container's port by specifying `-p` when running the image, with or without the `EXPOSE` keyword in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I tried to edit the post to let people know that, as @mc0e pointed, this answer is not correct but I couldn't because this post already has too many edits pending to be reviewed. I had no choice but to flag this answer to bring more attention to moderators to edit the post by themselves.

Comment: Downvote this because it is chosed as accepted but the answer will confuse people.

Comment: Can I actually expose a port which is already used and published by another container?

Comment: Downvote because option 2 is not correctly explained. The correct answer is below

Answer (score 381):

## Short answer:

- `EXPOSE` is a way of **documenting**
- `--publish` (or `-p`) is a way of **mapping** a *host port* to a running *container port*

---

Notice below that:

- `EXPOSE` is related to `Dockerfiles` ( **documenting** )
- `--publish` is related to `docker run ...` ( **execution / run-time** )

> ### Exposing and publishing ports
>
> In Docker networking, there are two different mechanisms that directly involve network ports: exposing and publishing ports. This applies to the default bridge network and user-defined bridge networks.
>
> - You expose ports using the `EXPOSE` keyword in the Dockerfile or the `--expose` flag to docker run. Exposing ports is a way of **documenting** which ports are used, **but does not actually map or open any ports**. Exposing ports is optional.
> - You publish ports using the `--publish` or `--publish-all` flag to `docker run`. This tells Docker which ports to open on the container’s network interface. When a port is published, it is mapped to an available high-order port (higher than `30000`) on the host machine, unless you specify the port to map to on the host machine at runtime. You cannot specify the port to map to on the host machine when you build the image (in the Dockerfile), because there is **no way to guarantee that the port will be available on the host machine where you run the image**.
>
> from: <s>[Docker container networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#exposing-and-publishing-ports)</s>
>
> **Update October 2019**: the above piece of text is no longer in the docs but an archived version is here: [docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#exposing-and-publishing-ports](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#exposing-and-publishing-ports)
>
> Maybe the current documentation is the below:
>
> > ### Published ports
> >
> > By default, when you create a container, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world. To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker containers which are not connected to the container's network, use the `--publish` or `-p` flag. This creates a firewall rule which maps a container port to a port on the Docker host.
>
> and can be found here: [docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports)

Also,

> ### EXPOSE
>
> ...The `EXPOSE` instruction **does not actually publish the port**. It functions as a type of **documentation** between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published.
>
> from: [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

---

## Service access when `EXPOSE` / `--publish` are not defined:

At [@Golo Roden's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333873/golo-roden) answer it is stated that::

> *"If you do not specify any of those, the service in the container will not be accessible from anywhere except from inside the container itself."*

Maybe that was the case at the time the answer was being written, but now it seems that even if you do not use `EXPOSE` or `--publish`, the `host` and other `containers` of the same network will be able to access a service you may start inside that container.

### How to test this:

I've used the following `Dockerfile`. Basically, I start with ubuntu and install a tiny web-server:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mini-httpd
```

I `build` the image as "testexpose" and `run` a new container with:

```
docker run --rm -it testexpose bash
```

Inside the container, I launch a few instances of `mini-httpd`:

```
root@fb8f7dd1322d:/# mini_httpd -p 80
root@fb8f7dd1322d:/# mini_httpd -p 8080
root@fb8f7dd1322d:/# mini_httpd -p 8090
```

I am then able to use `curl` from the host or other containers to fetch the home page of `mini-httpd`.

---

## Further reading

Very detailed articles on the subject by [Ivan Pepelnjak](https://twitter.com/ioshints):

- [Exposed ports](https://www.ipspace.net/kb/DockerSvc/10-Exposed.html)
- [Published ports](https://www.ipspace.net/kb/DockerSvc/20-Published.html)

Comment: this is now the correct answer. accepted answer is based on prior versions, it seems.

Comment: `EXPOSE` does actually do something and is not merely documentation. If you `run` with the `-P` flag, it publishes "`all exposed ports to random ports`".

Comment: The section on not publishing ports at all is wrong. I've just tried that and it just doesn't work and I wouldn't expect it to work. I tried something similar in compose too, using service names on the same network, and that also doesn't work. Also, as per papiro's comment, EXPOSE does have an effect with -P.

Comment: The section: **Service access when `EXPOSE` / `--publish` are not defined** is still valid and works as described above (I just tested it again). Maybe you tried it on docker for Windows or Mac (where networking is more complex)? On a Linux VM it works exactly as it's written, the example is complete and verifiable.

Answer (score 15):

See the official documentation reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

The `EXPOSE` allows you to define private (container) and public (host) ports to expose at image build time for when the container is running ***if*** you run the container with `-P`.

```
$ docker help run
...
  -P, --publish-all                    Publish all exposed ports to random ports
...
```

The public port and protocol are optional, if not a public port is specified, a random port will be selected on host by docker to expose the specified container port on Dockerfile.

A good pratice is do not specify public port, because it limits only one container per host ( a second container will throw a port already in use ).

You can use `-p` in `docker run`  to control what public port the exposed container ports will be connectable.

Anyway, If you do not use `EXPOSE` (with `-P` on docker run) nor `-p`, no ports will be exposed.

If you always use `-p` at `docker run` you do not need `EXPOSE` but if you use `EXPOSE` your `docker run`  command may be more simple, `EXPOSE` can be useful if you don't care what port will be exposed on host, or if you are sure of only one container will be loaded.

Comment: this is correct. When you have EXPOSE portNumber in Dockerfile, remember to invoke docker run with -P.

Comment: I'm wishing the language in this post was a bit more clear for those like me newer to some of the concepts.

Comment: BBaysinger, What concept you want to be clarify ?

Answer (score 12):

You expose ports using the EXPOSE keyword in the Dockerfile or the
--expose flag to docker run. Exposing ports is a way of documenting which
ports are used, but does not actually map or open any ports. Exposing ports
is optional.

Source: [github commit](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/2882/commits/8edf7c2b61e6ff59af09a421c595d65559b14c7a#diff-81e59a84f2bff40c4afd3a315e7afa38R503)

Comment: poor wording choice imo? if it's just documenting, they could've chosen... i dont know, anything BUT expose lol.

Comment: So using `--expose PORT` in CLI really does nothing? I would understand its place in Dockerfile, but why make it a cli flag?

Answer (score 6):

Most people use docker compose with networks. The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#maintainer-deprecated) states:

> The Docker network feature supports creating networks without the need to expose ports within the network, for detailed information see the overview of this feature).

Which means that if you use networks for communication between containers you don't need to worry about exposing ports.

Answer (score 1):

EXPOSE keyword lets owner to inform others that which ports are going to be used by the container mainly.

You can publish any port even if you don't specify the port in EXPOSE.

For example we create a Dockerfile with nginx image that exposes port 1234

```
FROM nginx:latest
EXPOSE 1234
```

and build it

> docker build -t porttest .

And run it with publishing 80 port to localhost:80

> docker run -p 80:80 porttest

When you go localhost:80, you will see nginx default page.
[Nginx default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGhTN.png)

Comment: But unfortunately, that is no answer to the question whether there is a way to make use of the port that's actually exposed in the image WITHOUT explicitly publishing it during container-creation. The answer would be: "yes, you can use -P option of 'docker run' to publish all the ports EXPOSEd in the Dockerfile"

Answer (score 0):

1. expose - will only allow that specific port to connect with container and it will use as "inter container communication " only
2. -p ( publish ) will map the host port with container port ( which you have already exposed in step 1 or in docker file ) and  once you expose it , you will need to map it so we use publish ,  it will then access container outside world/internet.

Answer (score -7):

EXPOSE is used to map local port container port 
ie : if you specify expose in docker file like

`EXPOSE 8090`

What will does it will map localhost port 8090 to container port 8090