# Docker port uncertainty

Tags: docker

I am trying to access a running app on a port that I defined using "EXPOSE".
Here is what I get:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
    NAMES
653d8ee23260        nginx:latest         "nginx -g 'daemon of   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        80/tcp, 443/tcp
    insane_thompson
007cfcd0f539        highlighter:latest   "java -jar -Xmx1500m   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        7777/tcp
    elated_kirch
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS     NAMES
653d8ee23260        nginx:latest         "nginx -g 'daemon of   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        80/tcp, 443/tcp    insane_thompson
007cfcd0f539        highlighter:latest   "java -jar -Xmx1500m   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        7777/tcp    elated_kirch

docker@boot2docker:~$ docker port 007cfcd0f539
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker port 653d8ee23260

docker@boot2docker:~$ docker port 653d8ee23260 80
FATA[0000] Error: No public port '80/tcp' published for 653d8ee23260

docker@boot2docker:~$ docker port 007cfcd0f539 7777
FATA[0000] Error: No public port '7777/tcp' published for 007cfcd0f539
```

Am I misunderstanding how the "port" command works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EXPOSE` in Dockerfile is not enough.

You need to specifically tell docker to expose port upon `docker run` with the `-P/-p` [flags](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run).

A much more detailed answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker).