# Connecting from psycopg2 on local machine to PostgreSQL db on Docker

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, psycopg2

I have used the following commands to create a Docker image with Postgres running on it:

`docker pull postgres
docker run --name test-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_secret_password -d postgres`

I then created a table called test and inserted some random data into a couple of rows. 
I am now trying to make a connection to this database table through psycopg2 in Python on my local machine.
I used the command `docker-machine ip default` to find out the IP address of the machine as 192.168.99.100 and am using the following to try and connect:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test-db' user='postgres' host='192.168.99.100' password='my_secret_password' port='5432'")
```

This is not working with the error message of "OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)"

.
.

Everything seems to be in order so I can't think why this would be refused.
According to the documentation for this postgres image, (at https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) this image includes EXPOSE 5432 (the postgres port) and the default username is postgres.

I also tried to get the IP address of the image itself with `docker inspect test-db | grep IPAddress | awk 'print{$2}' | tr -d '",'` that I found on SA to a slightly related article, but that IP address didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with a different client like `psql`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `EXPOSE` instruction may not be doing what you expect. It is used for links and inter-container communication inside the Docker network. When connecting to a container from outside the Docker bridge network you need to publish to port with `-p`. Try adding `-p 5432:5432` to your `docker run` command so that it looks like:

```
docker run --name test-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_secret_password -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

Here is a decent explanation of the differences between publish and exposed ports: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22150099/684908. Hope this helps!