# Docker container with multiple configurable ports

Tags: docker

I have a container that runs a node app with three servers: one server for public data and two webpack servers. By default these run on ports 3000, 3001, and 3002, but these ports can all be configured.

It seems that I would be able to run the container like so:

```
docker run -p 3000:3003 -p 3001:3004 -p 3002:3005 -e 'APP_PORT=3003' \
  -e 'NG_PORT=3004' -e 'RC_PORT=3005' --expose 3003 --expose 3004 --expose 3005 \
  ajcrites/webf
```

However there are two problems with this approach:

1. There is a tremendous amount of redundancy
2. I want the default ports to be used/exposed if nothing is specified

Is there a simpler way to expose all of the configurable ports whether or not they are changed from the defaults?

Comment: I post this comment just in case.

It may not be what you're searching for (I'm not sure I understand well what you're searching for, if that's not relevant I apologize), but there is the **-P** option that automatically assigns external ports to exposed ports.

Plus you can expose ports by adding an **EXPOSE** directive to a dockerfile.

Comment: yoiu don't need to repeat the `-p`, you can specify several different port (without them being contiguous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't want to expose ALL ports, however you can expose and bind by range since at least docker 1.5:

```
docker run -p 3000-3002:3003-3005
```

I don't think you need to use --expose when you publish.

Comment: Don't you still need to do `--expose` with the same port numbers as well?

Comment: You can expose a range too.

Comment: @ExplosionPills  Expose only exposes ports to other running services in the running docker container, but not outside, so you could always expose a wide range if you don't need to lock down by port inside docker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker

Comment: @ExplosionPills If you publish you're not having to explicilty expose.  Expose is needed if you don't publish to make them available inter-service.

Comment: `-p 3000-3002:3003-3005` does this automatically map the ports one-to-one?

Comment: @ExplosionPills yep, I believe so.