# How to expose ports defined in EXPOSE without explicitly setting ports via CLI options?

Tags: docker

[Difference between "expose" and "publish" in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker) this post describes 3 different options to expose ports:

> If you do not specify [`EXPOSE` or `-p`], the service in the container
>   will not be accessible from anywhere except from inside the container
>   itself.
>
> If you `EXPOSE` a port, the service in the container is not accessible
>   from outside Docker, but from inside other Docker containers. So this
>   is good for inter-container communication.
>
> If you `EXPOSE` and `-p` a port, the service in the container is
>   accessible from anywhere, even outside Docker.

What if I have defined `EXPOSE` in Dockerfile and I want container to expose these ports to the host?

Example:

If I have the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:6

# ...

CMD node ./dist/bin/server.js

EXPOSE 8001
EXPOSE 8002
```

and I run `docker run`, I want mapping to be setup `8001:8001`, `8002:8002`.

However, I need to do this without hardcoding the port values using `-p` option.

The use case:

Migrating from VM based deployment system to Docker based deployment system. Each docker container is running in its own VM. Therefore, there will not be conflicts with other services.

Comment: Yes, that's still a problem I think. You could think about using `docker-compose`

Answer (score 0):

To map to specific ports like you've asked you have to use the -p PORT:PORT option.

The other option is to use -P to publish all ports and then docker will randomly assign ports starting typically in the 32700 range to the various ports are that are defined by the image.

Comment: I have described these options in the original question. It does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem with a little [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
docker run $(cat Dockerfile | grep EXPOSE | sed -n 's/EXPOSE \([0-9]*\)/-p \1:\1/p' | tr '\n' ' ') app
```