# What's the difference between EXPOSE a port from dockerfile with mapping ports when running a container?

Tags: docker, port

I know I can EXPOSE a port (e.g. 8888) in dockerfile. With this dockerfile I can build a image, then I run`docker run --name container1 -p 8888:8888 image`. Via this method I can access port 8888 in the container.

The second way I don't EXPOSE any port from dockerfile. With this dockerfile I can build image2, then I run`docker run --name container2 -p 8888:8888 image2`.

I wanna ask what is the difference between them ?

I find something strange.

In `container1` I run `jupyter notebook --port 8888`. I can both access the `port 8888` from the host running the container (`localhost:8888`) and the computer(`hostip:8888`) in the same local network

In `container2` I run `jupyter notebook --port 8888`. I can access the `port 8888` from the host running the container (`localhost:8888`), but I can not access the `port 8888` via `hostip:8888` from the computer in the same local network.

Comment: from the doc at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/expose `EXPOSE does not make the ports of the container accessible to the host`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "expose" and "publish" in docker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker)