# What is the difference between EXPOSE and PUBLISH directives?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#exposing-and-publishing-ports) I noticed this: "You publish ports using the PUBLISH keyword in the Dockerfile".

Is this a bad idea? I have literally never seen a dockerfile with a PUBLISH directive, why isn't this used? And how do I use it in conjunction with -p or -P with docker run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "expose" and "publish" in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker)

Comment: No, I'm asking about the PUBLISH keyword/directive specifically

Comment: `PUBLISH === --publish === -p`. It's a duplicate ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That documentation was incorrect and has been [fixed](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/4863). There is no `PUBLISH` Dockerfile directive, it's a run time option only

```
  -p, --publish list                   Publish a container's port(s) to the host
  -P, --publish-all                    Publish all exposed ports to random ports
```

For the details of the two concepts see [Difference between "expose" and "publish" in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker)