# Docker access container IP/Port directly

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I have docker container for experiments. So I don't know which ports I will use later when I trying new apps. 
Isn't it possible to access docker container application with ip/port from the host without exposing it in the docker-run command?

Comment: Basically, you want to expose new port in running container right? Here is the related discussion in docker forum. I have tried some of them, and find them working fine. https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-expose-port-on-running-container/3252/14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Docker for Mac is unable to route traffic to containers, and from containers back to the host.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers

Answer (score 13):

**update:** the OP didn't provide that it was about `docker-for-mac` in the original question, so the rest cannot be applied if you are using this version of docker.

---

**Original answer:**

Yes, you can do that.

Let's say that you have a container named `boring_pare` and a web app running on port `8080`. You can access it **from your host machine** by requesting `http://[ip_of_boring_pare]:8080`. If you are using the default docker network, this ip will probably be in the `172.17.0.xxx` range.

To find this IP, you can `inspect` your container by using:

```
docker container inspect boring_pare
```

---

Also, you mention:

> Isn't it possible to access docker container application with ip/port from the host without **exposing** it in the docker-run command?

The correct term here would be **publishing**. Further reading:

- [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) about `EXPOSE` / Dockerfile

  > ...The `EXPOSE` instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the `-p` flag on `docker run` to publish and map one or more ports, or the `-P` flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to to high-order ports.
- [Difference between “expose” and “publish” in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker)

---

**Update** to answer to [@robie2011](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2248405/robie2011)'s comment:

Below, I run 3 commands:

1. run a `nginx` container without publishing `port 80` to a `host` port
2. inspect its `ip address`
3. use `curl` from `host` to access the `nginx` home page

My console output:

```
$ docker run --rm --name some-nginx -d nginx
0e53d3b5ef6d65a4731c4066f3523c5ecd3c118abedae44b33e89fdf8e401632

$ docker container inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' some-nginx
172.17.0.3

$ curl 172.17.0.3
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
$
```

Comment: Didn't worked in my case. Here two examples: `docker run --name some-nginx -d nginx` here is the proof that this should work on port 80
`docker run -p9999:80 --name some-nginx2 -d nginx`

Comment: @robie2011 I added at the end of my answer the results I get when I `curl` from `host` to the `container` run by your first command.

Comment: I followed your steps but it didn't work for me. Im using macosx and have following runtime https://pastebin.com/q866LHRc

maybe it's a mac issue?

Comment: @robie2011 exactly `The docker (Linux) bridge network is not reachable from the macOS host.`. I think @tgogos was not using MacOS

Comment: Get just the ip: `docker container inspect docker_container_name | jq -r '.[0].NetworkSettings.Networks.web.IPAddress'`

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure i follow the question, but for mac you could use

- ip: 0.0.0.0
- port: the port you are exposing

For example, i have a compose file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: changeit
    ports:
      - target: 5432
        published: 5432
        protocol: tcp
        mode: ingress
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@mail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: changeit
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - admin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin

volumes:
  db-data:
  admin-data:
```

On `docker compose up` a network `db_default` is created (check logs)

There are 3 scenarios

- To access pg-admin you open browser and type 0.0.0.0:8080 .
- To create a database from pg-admin (Right click 'Servers' / Register / Server) under Connection tab, for Host name / address you specify "db". That is because you are inside the network created by compose
- To connect to the db from outside (say for some reason you wish to connect to db from a local script using a database connection url) you will use (for user postgres, driver psycopg2: postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:changeit@0.0.0.0:5432/your_db_name_here

A note:

Some peer recommend doing `docker inspect db_default` and find the IPv4 of the db container and use that in the url. This will not work as robie2011 said