# Want to expose port to a docker using Python3.x api by docker

Tags: python-3.x, dockerpy

```
docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub --expose 7092 selenium/node-chrome
```

Here's [docker link](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html)

I want to code above expose option using python docker api.

As a result i want 7092 port should be exposed to selenium/node-chrome docker.

**Result:**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES

1fcb8c15a059        selenium/node-chrome   "/opt/bin/entry_point"   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        7092/tcp                 selenium-node-chrome
```

Please help me in this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a port mapping like `docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub --expose 7092 selenium/node-chrome -p 7092:7092`. First number is the port that will be exposed, the second one is the port it gets mapped to in the container.

See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p-expose) to get the official docker run reference.

There is another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker) explaining the difference between exposing a port and publishing it.

Comment: Expose option is working for me, thats not the issue. i want to automate it using python [Library](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html)

Answer (score 0):

To only expose a port to other docker containers but not the host, this worked for me:

```
import docker
from docker.models.containers import Container
client = docker.from_env()
container: Container = client.containers.run(
    ...
    ports={5432: []},
    ...
)
```