# Docker automatically binds port

Tags: node.js, docker, networking, dockerfile

**When I am *not* exposing any ports when writing my Dockerfile, nor am I binding any ports when running `docker run`, I am still able to interact with applications running inside the container. Why?**

---

I am writing my Dockerfile for my Node application. It's pretty simple and looks like this:

```
FROM node:8

COPY . .
RUN yarn
RUN yarn run build

ARG PORT=80
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD yarn run serve
```

Using this Dockerfile, I was able to build the image using `docker build`

```
$ cd ~/project/dir/
$ docker build . --build-arg PORT=8080
```

And run it using  `docker run`

```
$ docker run -p 8080 <image-id>
```

I then accessed the application, running inside the Docker container, on an IP address like `http://172.17.0.12:8080/` and it works.

---

However, when I removed the `EXPOSE` instruction from the Dockerfile, and remove the `-p` option in `docker run`, *the application still works*! It's like Docker is automatically binding my ports

---

Additional Notes:

1. It appears that [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594352/2317532) have experienced the same issue
2. I have tried rebuilding my image using `--no-cache` after I removed the `EXPOSE` instructions, but this problem still exists.
3. Using `docker inspect`, I see no entries for `Config.ExposedPorts`

Answer (score 2):

the `EXPOSE` command in Dockerfile really doesnt do much and I think it is more for people that read the Dockerfile to know what ports/services are running inside the container. However, the `EXPOSE` is usefull when you start contianer with capital `-P` argument (-P, --publish-all                    Publish all exposed ports to random ports)

```
docker run -P my_image
```

but if you are using the lower case `-p` you have to specify the source:destination port... See this [thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/what-is-the-use-of-expose-in-docker-file/37726)

If you dont write `EXPOSE` in Dockerfile it doesnt have any influence to the app inside container, it is only for the capital `-P` argument....

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am also not specifying the `-p` or `-P` flags, so I am not binding the ports from my host to the container. So it shouldn't be working.

Comment: ok, but the IP address `172.17.0.12` is the IP of the container so it will always succeed... the `-p` or `-P` binds the port of all host network interfaces

Comment: i assume you use the default docker network, and all the docker run commands are working with default docker network, if you dont want this behavior, you will have to create own `docker network`

Comment: from your host example: if you do `-p 9000:8080` you can access the container service at least with two options 1) `http://localhost:9000/` or 2) `http://172.17.0.12:8080` (or other container IP)

Comment: Right...that makes a lot more sense now thank you! I will read a bit more about networking and get back to you! Thank you very much!