# Which port is now listening? Expose vs port?

Tags: docker

I have a simple web app which starts a web server on port port 5002. Now I want to docker this app. But I am rather confused. Should I give an expose command inside the dockerfile or do I just give a port with the docker run command like

```
docker run -p 4000:4000 myapp
```

If I do this what port is my app now listening? I use the docker toolbox fo windows. When I run this command inside the toolbox the app says the server is running now on prt 5002. But how do I reach this port now because there are two port like 4000 and 5002.

I am a beginner in docker. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't reach port 5002 when you forward 4000 to 4000. Forward 4000 to 5002 instead.

Comment: what is this 4000? So I have to run docker run  -5002:4000? or the other way around?

Comment: The other way around. `-p 4000:5002`

Comment: wher is this 4000 come from. SHould I give this port with the Expose command inside the dockerfile?

Comment: I have no clue where this 4000 is coming from, you mentioned it in your question: `docker run -p 4000:4000 myapp`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "expose" and "publish" in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/what-is-the-difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confuse the concept of listening and forwarding. Docker containers operate on a separate network and your host can reach the network only if you configure it to.

When you start your app in a container, it listens on port `5002` regardless. It can be reached on that said port `5002` from another container if you connect another container to the same network.

Port forwarding says which ports from your host are redirected to which port inside your container. When you do `-p 4000:4000` it simply tells to "connect" to port `4000` inside the container when you connect to `4000` on your host.

If you need to connect to your app, which listens on `5002`, but require it to be `4000` on your host, you must do `-p 4000:5002`.

P.S. you should bother accepting answers to your questions. It helps the community and future googlers to see if the answer helped or not.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is following. This web app which I want to docker (port 5002) should listening (connected) to another app outside from docker (in this app i have to give the host from the dockered app). What should I do in this situation?

Comment: First, read the help section on [How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and familiarize yourself with how question asking on Stack Overflow works. Your question was about listening and forwarding, which I and @tkausl managed to answer (IMO). If you have a new question (your comment suggests you do), then you should open a separate question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).