# Does specifying ports in a docker-compose file override the ports exposed in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I have a Dockerfile in a folder called `foo` with the following line:

```
EXPOSE 80
```

And I have a docker-compose that builds the container like this:

```
services:
  foo:
    build: foo
    ...
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
```

On the host machine, I'm only able to reach port `5000`, while `80` refuses to connect.

So what exactly happens? Does docker-compose completely override the Dockerfile's `EXPOSE` commands? Does port `80` get exposed to only other containers on the internal network?

(I'm not really asking because I have a problem -- I just saw that the `EXPOSE 80` still happened to be in my Dockerfile and I'm curious if it affects anything.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "expose" and "publish" in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/what-is-the-difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `docker-compose up`, then the dockerfile ports will be overridden.
When you use `docker run`, the ports mentioned in dockerfile will be exposed.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I can remove some muck from my Dockerfile then!

Comment: Yes, you can only keep port mappings in docker compose file.