# AdminMongo with docker-compose doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to access to my mongo database on docker with [adminmongo](https://hub.docker.com/r/mrvautin/adminmongo/).

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ~/data:/data/db
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 6016
  adminmongo:
    image: mrvautin/adminmongo
    expose:
      - 1234
    links:
      - mongo:mongo
```

When i do a `docker-compose up` everything works fine, adminmongo also return me this : `adminmongo_1_544d9a6f954c | adminMongo listening on host: http://localhost:1234`

But when i go to `localhost:1234` my navigator is telling me this page doesn't exist.

Here's what a `docker ps` return me :

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
9c27d4a89254        mrvautin/adminmongo   "/bin/sh -c 'node ap…"   38 seconds ago      Up 33 seconds       1234/tcp              iris_adminmongo_1_544d9a6f954c
2a7496a8c56a        mongo                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   40 minutes ago      Up 38 seconds       6016/tcp, 27017/tcp   iris_mongo_1_7f00356a3adc
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found 2 issues here:

**1st:** Exposing a port is not enough. `expose` is just documentation, you need to `publish` (bind) a port to the host to be reachable. This is how it's done:

```
ports:
  - 1234:1234
```

**2nd:** you have to configure `adminmongo` to listen to `0.0.0.0` because by default it starts listening on `127.0.0.1` and this makes it accessible only inside the container itself. From the [documentation page](https://hub.docker.com/r/mrvautin/adminmongo/) you've included in your question, the **Configuration** section states that this can be done by passing an environment variable:

> All above parameters are usable through the environment which makes it very handy to when using adminMongo as a docker container! just run `docker run -e HOST=yourchoice -e PORT=1234 ...`

Since you are using `docker-compose`, this is done by the following:

```
environment:
  - HOST=0.0.0.0
```

**Working example:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ~/data:/data/db
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 6016
  adminmongo:
    image: mrvautin/adminmongo
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: It works ! So if i understand doing an `expose: - 1234:1234` mean that docker expose the container's 1234 local port outside of the container so it can be accessed at localhost:1234. Am i right ?
**Edit** :
It's ok i understand now.

Comment: Containers "live" in their isolated network namespace. By using `expose` you just inform the docker daemon that your container is listening on port `1234`. That's just documentation. When you want to bind that port to a host port, you `publish` it. I've written an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/what-is-the-difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker/47594352#47594352) which has more details.

Comment: adding 
environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0 in docker-compose.yml
solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Example of docker-compose works :

```
version: '3'

services:
  server:
    container_name: docker_api_web_container
    image: docker_api_web
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/node-app/src
      - ./package.json:/usr/src/node-app/package.json
    environment:
     - ENV=DEVELOPMENT
     - PORT=4010
    ports:
      - '9000:4010'
    depends_on:
      - 'mongo'

  mongo:
    container_name: docker_mongo_container
    image: 'mongo'
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

  adminmongo:
    container_name: docker_adminmongo_container
    image: mrvautin/adminmongo
    links: ['mongo:mongo']
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - '1234:1234'
```

Comment: Perhaps can you explain what is different about your solution that makes it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose your service to the outside world like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ~/data:/data/db
    restart: always
  adminmongo:
    image: mrvautin/adminmongo
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
```

Now you can access your adminmongo by http://localhost:1234.

And you don't have to use links here.Since compose creates a network and joins all services in the compose files. You can access other containers with their service names.