# Map Spring Boot port to 80 in docker container

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, docker, port

I am specifying `PORT 80` in Spring boot `application.properties` like this
`server.port=80`
So when running on localhost, this runs on port 80

Now I need to run it in a docker container and I did some hit and trial on the port mapping.

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 DOCKERHUB_REPO/DOCKER_IMAGE
```

Then I did

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 DOCKERHUB_REPO/DOCKER_IMAGE
```

None of these worked. How should I proceed? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Ports less than 1024 does not work as non root user...what is the problem by using defaults like 8080?

Comment: Can you send the logs of the docker container?

Answer (score 1):

I think first of all you should make sure that the application within the docker container indeed starts on port 80.

```
docker exec -it <process_id> bash

curl http://localhost:80/<somthing, some reset or actuator if you have it>
```

Once you have it set, make sure you've specified `EXPOSE 80` in Dockerfile. Read [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/what-is-the-difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker) to understand what exacly is `-p` and `EXPOSE` options are doing.

Now, running with `-p` is good, but maybe you don't have permissions to access port 80. In order to eliminate the docker related issues from the picture I suggest to test with another port which is more than 1024, something like 8080 for example.
If it works (with Expose and -p options) than its security on the host machine for sure