# Accessing Python WebApp in Docker Connection Refused

Tags: docker

I have a web app in `python3`. I'am trying to access the web app from another Machine on my network (cloud environment). The web app works.

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.8.0-slim as builder
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install gcc -y \
    && apt-get clean
COPY app/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt
COPY ./app /app

# Production image
FROM python:3.8.0-slim as app
COPY --from=builder /root/.local /root/.local
COPY --from=builder /app /app
WORKDIR app
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT gunicorn main:app -b 0.0.0.0:5000

$docker build -t simu .

$docker run --name simu --detach -p 5000:5000  -it simu:v1
11a8e9e2f7f2d70d39cac2b3e2a14c25ae2bf9536db005dee1d473aa588139ae
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
11a8e9e2f7f2        simu:v1             "/bin/sh -c 'gunicor…"   3 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   simu

$curl -X POST {} http://localhost:5000
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Why I receive that error?

**UPDATE**

If I run the container as

```
/usr/bin/docker run --name simu --detach --network host  -e REGISTRAR_URL=http://localhost:8500 -it simu:v1
```

The service is accessible from the same machine:

```
curl -X POST {} http://localhost:5000
curl: (3) <url> malformed
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

But it is not from another machine on the same LAN:

```
$curl -X POST http://algo:5000/generate-prod
curl: (7) Failed connect to algo:5000; Connection refused
```

I have stopped firewalld also.
If I run the application without the container everything works, so I think there must be something in the neworking with docker which is not set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expose the port but you do not publish the port. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/what-is-the-difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker) on the difference. You need to add `-p 5000:5000` to the `docker run` command.