# Flask App with Gunicorn Dockerized, Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000, but URL not responding

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn, ubuntu-server

On an Ubuntu Linux server, I have a Flask App (with 4 routes) running as a Docker image.

My Dockerfile -

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev
COPY . /backend
WORKDIR /backend
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=4 wsgi:app
```

When I run it -

```
sudo docker run -it flaskApp:1.16
```

stdout shows

```
[2020-10-01 14:03:25 +0000] [6] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-10-01 14:03:25 +0000] [6] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (6)
[2020-10-01 14:03:25 +0000] [6] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-10-01 14:03:25 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2020-10-01 14:03:25 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2020-10-01 14:03:25 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2020-10-01 14:03:25 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
```

But when I use the public IP of the server to access the App and API, it cannot connect.

1. Do I need to configure something else?
2. Is my Dockerfile correct?

Comment: You need to publish the container port to the host, see [Container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/). [The `EXPOSE` instruction does not actually publish the port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose). See more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22111060/1782792).

Answer (score 3):

Docker must expose the port via the `-p`/`--publish` command! [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports)

```sh
sudo docker run -it -p=8000:8000 flaskApp:1.16
```

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation says](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) you need to expose the port to be accesed from the host. In your case the correct command would be:

`sudo docker run -it -p 8000:8000 flaskApp:1.16`