# Dockerized flask web app throws 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a basic REST API implemented in Flask. I want to try using Docker to containerize it. I'm completely new to Docker, but based on what I was able to figure out on various forums, this is what I have set up.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

WORKDIR /myapplication

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
ENV FLASK_APP="app.py"

CMD ["python3", "-m" , "flask", "run"]
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.0.2
```

I then go to the Terminal, and run
`$ docker build -t myapp:latest .`

The build is successful, and I can see `my app` listed in the Docker Desktop app

I then run

```
$ docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 myapp:latest

 * Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Docker Desktop shows `myapp` is in use.

So far, so good. But this is where I start running into issues.

I am also using Postman for API route testing. If I were to run the application outside of Docker, and I go to `127.0.0.1:5000/data` or any of my other routes, I get a response just fine. But with the Docker build running, I am no longer able to access this route, or any other route.

I have tried endless combinations: 127.0.0.1:5000, 127.0.0.1:8080, localhost, localhost:5000, localhost:8080, to no avail.

The only one that gives me ANY response is 127.0.0.1:5000. The response I do get is a `403 Forbidden`, with Postman saying "The request was a legal request, but the server is refusing to respond to it."

For what its worth, I am running this on a new M1 Pro MacBook. I know the new Macs are touchy with permissioning, so I wouldn't be surprised if permissions were the issue.

I really don't know what to do or where to go from here, every source I've tried has given me a slight variation on what I have already attempted, and I'm no closer to getting this to work. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your docker application is running on port `5000` inside the container, but in your docker `run` command you are binding `port` 8080 with port `8080` inside the container which should be `5000` instead. As there is nothing running on port `8080` inside the container hence you are getting the `403` error

the command should be

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:5000 myapp:latest
```

from host machine you can access the app on port 8080, i.e:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/data # access from host machine
```

`127.0.0.1:5000/data`  # access from inside container

I just noticed, you didn't expose the app on internet/external use, in the last line of your Dockerfile add arg "--host=0.0.0.0"

```
CMD ["python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

after docker build and publishing the port you should be able to access the app.

Comment: This did not solve it. I tried exposing `EXPOSE 5000` as well like the other comment suggested, and neither worked.

Comment: `EXPOSE 5000` will expose the app to `5000` inside the container, to access from your host machine you need to publish the port i,e you should forward the traffic from correct port which is `5000` in your case with local port . please read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/what-is-the-difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker

Comment: I tried `EXPOSE 8080`, `docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 myapp:latest` as well as `EXPOSE 5000` `docker run --rm -it -p 8080:5000 myapp:latest`. Neither work when going to 127.0.0.1:5000/data

Comment: from host machine you can access the app using `8080` not `5000`. 

try: 127.0.0.1:8080/data after running the container

Comment: Visiting `127.0.0.1:8080/data` in Postman with `EXPOSE 8080`, `docker run --rm -it -p 8080:5000 myapp:latest` gives `Error: socket hang up` now

Comment: I have edited the post, please check again. you should expose the app externally, localhost is not a exposing the app for external use.

Comment: This ended up working: `CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]`, `$ docker run --rm -it -p 8080:5000 myapp:latest`, accessing endpoints at `127.0.0.1:8080/data`

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working, thank you @Tasnuva

Dockerfile, append CMD with `--host`

```
CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

In the CLI,
`$ docker run --rm -it -p 8080:5000 myapp:latest`

Accessing endpoints in Postman at `127.0.0.1:8080`

Answer (score -1):

In dockerfile you need to expose your port

```
...
ENV FLASK_APP="app.py"
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python3", "-m" , "flask", "run"]
```

Comment: Still not working, I have `EXPOSE 5000` in my Dockerfile now, and I deleted the old build. I rebuilt the image with `docker build -t myapp:latest .`, and ran with `docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 myapp:latest`. The server starts as usual, and when I go to Postman 127.0.0.1:5000/data, I get the same 403 Forbidden

Comment: It should not work, the root problem is in docker run command, OP is binding the host port with port `8080` of container but his application is running on port `5000`, either he should expose the app to 8080 inside container or bind the host port with correct port which is 5000